# Custom Cut, Copy & Paste operations for WKWebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I am developing a Cocoa application to wrap a JavaScript web application I have developed that provides editing of SVG graphics. I have the following question, which is motivated by a desire to customize the Cut, Copy and Paste operations and their associated menu items.

How can I either:

- substitute my own responder in place of WKWebView or
- customize its responses to `validateMenuItem:` and the `cut:`, `copy:` and `paste:` selectors?

I am particularly interested in solutions that retain the useful WKWebView functionality of providing Cut, Copy and Paste for text fields.

Any help would be much appreciated. Detail follows.

---

The purpose of my Cocoa wrapper is threefold:

1. to provide persistence
2. to provide clipboard integration
3. to provide printing

I've achieved 1, but am blocked on 2 and 3; this question is about 2.

Specifically, I cannot get the framework to call any implementation of `validateMenuItem:` that I provide — as a result, I have no control over when the Cut, Copy or Paste menu items are available for the user to select.

I have tried the following:

1. mark my NSViewController subclass as accepting first responder and override `validateMenyItem:` there — my implementation was never called
2. subclass WKWebView and override `validateMenuItem:` — my implementation was never called
3. subclass NSWindowController and override `validateMenuItem:` — my implementation was never called

Now, my wrapped web app has some text fields. When I give one of those focus and when it is appropriate (text is on the clipboard; I highlight some text), the Cut, Copy and Paste options in my Edit menu automagically activate. They even work. (I like this functionality, and would like to retain it.) I therefore suspect that what is happening is that the WKWebView, as my current first responder, is intercepting any call to `validateMenuItem:` along the responder chain. But I also need to be able to activate menu items according to other states in my wrapped web app — for example, when the user selects an SVG graphic.

---

**Update**

I have done additional digging, in trying to figure out a solution to my problem. In my WKWebView subclass, I added a custom `@IBAction`. I created a menu item for it on my story board and wired the menu item to FirstResponder, choosing my new action.

And my `validateMenuItem:` on my WKWebView subclass was called. But *only* for that new selector, not for the `copy:` selector associated with the `@IBAction` that I had previously added to my WKWebView subclass.

Now, my `copy:` method, marked with @IBAction and having the method signature for things that Interface Builder (or whatever it's called these days) is able to use, is not marked `override`. When I tried to mark it `override`, I got an error. Apparently, WKWebView does not provide a `copy:id` method — even though it provides Copy functionality and handles the menu item correctly, when text in a text field is selected.

So it appears that, somehow, WKWebView automatically (and always) handles validation for certain selectors typically bound to menus — specifically, `cut:`, `copy:` and `paste:`. Moreover, subclassing WKWebView and overriding `validateMenuItem:` is insufficient to interrupt/take control over this default behavior. Which *seems* odd.

But from reading other posts on WKWebView on StackOverflow, I am aware that WKWebView is actually quite a complex piece of functionality. Of particular interest/concern to me is that WKWebView actually runs the web content in a separate process. I therefore wonder if something related to that separate process is responsible for menu validation and handling `cut:`, `copy:` and `paste:` — something internal to the framework and to which I don't have access.

I'm still hoping for a solution. Hopefully the above update will prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, I was also looking at porting over a vector design tool to the Mac via WKWebView and encountered the same problem. It looks like you can actually control the cut/copy/paste menu items from [inside JavaScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/CopyAndPaste.html). If you add `beforecopy` and `beforecut` event handlers and `preventDefault()` them, then the cut and copy menu items will be enabled. I can't seem to enable the paste menu item though. I think that may be due to a [long-running bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=75891). You can still ⌘-V on the keyboard, and the paste will still happen because in that case, WebKit will skip calling `beforepaste` and just trigger the `paste` event directly. I just can't figure out enabling the paste menu item. As a workaround, I've created a "fake" Paste menu option that doesn't go to the normal `paste:` selector but to my own selector that the WKWebView won't intercept.

Answer (score 1):

... 5 years later....

Please have a look at my own answer to another problem: [Manipulate paste content in WKWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124006/manipulate-paste-content-in-wkwebview/61274962#61274962) this solution involves method Swizzling and probably can easily solve your problem too.